# Android Studio How can I reference a activity itself inside of a Static method

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using a "**createUserWithEmailAndPassword**" method from Firebase and I need to send a context (activity) to it.

But this is inside a Static method (have to be this way because I'm using Fragments.). So, I collect all the data inside the Fragment and send to "registerUser" method in the MainActivity.

So, because this methos (registerUser) is a Static Mode, the MainActivity is not being referenced by the "**createUser...**" from Firebase.

I've tried to use "This" keyword. I've tried to use "new" keyword, like:

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
```

But both does not work and using the "new" keyword, the code is not even compiled.

Someone to help me?

The image below shows the code inside the MainActivity.
[image]

Comment: i don't think the `static` method keyword is needed here since your `MainActivity` will always be instantiated on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really so glad to your answers and they are very enlightening to me.

A brazilian friend help me in this task:
[image]

He taught me to write this code inside the Fragment, using `getActivity` in `onAttach` from Fragment and declare a `private Context context`. So, I could use `getActivity` with Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods, by definition, don't run in the context of an enclosing class instance.  There is no `this` instance to reference.  If you need to reference another class instance from a static method, you will need to pass it as a parameter to the function.

```
public static String cadUsario(MainActivity activity, Usario pUsario) {
    // now use activity where needed
}
```

Consider also not using a static method at all. That might not be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass context object of your Activity to another Activity with constructor parameters. Check this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786189/1744705)

Your problem; If you want to use context object in **same** class with static context, you can create a global variable like this;

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static Context context;

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                context = this;

            }

        public static String cadUsusario(Usuario pUsuario){

        // use "context" variable by itself or create new variable. It's up to you.
        Context myContext = context;
        // your codes below

        }
}
```